# Use code to modify Excel formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel 2010 workbook with 22 worksheets in it.  The first worksheet is labeled DATA, where data is entered by a user.  Row A1-N1 contain labels.  Rows A2-A18 contains data for January 2015 for the 17 locations beginning as cell A2, i.e. row 2 contains data for location 1, row 3 for location 3, etc.  February data begins at row 19, March begins at row 36, etc.

On each worksheet A1-M1 are labels and rows 2-13 are the months January - December.  Cell B2 on worksheet #2 references cell J2 on the worksheet DATA.  The other formulas on row 2 of worksheet #2 reference cells on row 2 on worksheet DATA.  Row 3 of worksheet #2 references cells on row 19 of DATA.  In column N of each location worksheet has a number in cell N2 that corresponds to the appliable row on the worksheet DATA.

Here is an example of one of my formulas:

> =(IF(ISBLANK(DATA!D2),"-",IF(ISERROR(DATA!E2/DATA!D2),"N/A",(DATA!E2/DATA!D2)))).

I would like to have VB code, or a macro?, that would edit every formula on each worksheet by replacing the current number in the formula with the number in column N of that same row, i.e. if N7 contained the number 88 the code would alter any formula on that row by removing the current number in the formula and replacing with the number 88.

**Additional information:**

On each worksheet there are different formulas for columns B-M.  The code would need to take the number in column N for that row and replace whatever number is in that formula with the number in column N of that row, for each row, for each worksheet.

Currently, I have to touch each formula on every worksheet and this is too time consuming.  Beginning in April the locations will increase from 17 to 148 which will require coding to make the appropriate changes.

DATA worksheet image

[image]

1R location worksheet image

[image]

Comment: What range/cells are the formulas you want to change in? Is there always the same number of rows in each of the columns? What have you tried so far?

Comment: On each location worksheet formulas are within the range B2:M13 and each location worksheet contains the same number of rows/colmuns.  I have no coding experience so I have not tried any form of coding. I have been modifying each formula by using the find/replace on each  row of every worksheet.

Comment: Can you show us how your data is organized? Upload a screen shot in any free image hosting site (e.g. http://imgur.com) and post the link in comment or edit your post

Comment: Is there a way to upload the spreadsheet to this post?  I will remove the excess worksheets and only include the DATA worksheet and one location worksheet.  There are multiple formulas on the location worksheet.  Would it be helpful to post them?

Comment: It would be, I dunno of what are good sites for hosting it though. The thing is, it is kinda hard to know what search-pattern to use to find and replace a number in a random formula. Will the formulas always be of the form which you showed above? Will the number you want to replace always be the same (i.e. 2 in your sample formula)? Will there be numbers in the formulas which you do *not* want to replace? Without knowing this, it is a bit tricky to even begin to come up with a solution.

Comment: On the worksheet DATA row 2 contains data for January 2015 for location 1R, row 19 has February data, row 36 has March data, etc.  Row 3 contains January data for location 2R, 20 for February, etc.  This follows for the remaining 15 locations.  Here are the formulas in the location worksheets:  B2 =DATA!J2, C2 =DATA!C2, D2 =DATA!D2, E2 =(IF(ISBLANK(DATA!D2),"-",IF(ISERROR(DATA!E2/DATA!D2),"N/A",(DATA!E2/DATA!D2)))),

Comment: F2 =DATA!F2, G2 =(IF(ISBLANK(DATA!F2),"-",IF(ISERROR(DATA!G2/DATA!F2),"N/A",(DATA!G2/DATA!F2)))), H2 =DATA!H2, I2 =(IF(ISBLANK(DATA!I2),"-",IF(ISERROR(DATA!I2/DATA!H2),"N/A",(DATA!I2/DATA!H2)))), J2 =(IF(ISBLANK(DATA!J2),"-",IF(ISERROR(DATA!K2/DATA!J2),"N/A",(DATA!K2/DATA!J2)))), K2 =(IF(ISBLANK(DATA!J2),"-",IF(ISERROR(DATA!L2/DATA!J2),"N/A",(DATA!L2/DATA!J2)))), L2 =(IF(ISBLANK(DATA!J2),"-",IF(ISERROR(DATA!M2/DATA!J2),"N/A",(DATA!M2/DATA!J2)))), and M2 =(IF(ISBLANK(DATA!J2),"-",IF(ISERROR(DATA!N2/DATA!J2),"N/A",(DATA!N2/DATA!J2)))).

Comment: (1) The number I want to replaced will be the same for that row only.  In column N on location worksheet 1R I have the value 3 in N2, 20 in N3, 37 in N4, etc.  On location worksheet 2R (the next worksheet) I have the value 4 in N2, 21 in N3, 38 in N4, etc.  (2)There are no numbers that will not be altered, meaning that every number in every formula will need to be modified to the number in column N of that row, since the same number applies to every formula in that row. (3)

Comment: Row 3 of worksheet 1R should have the number 19 in all formulas, row 4 should have row 36, etc.  Row 2 of the next location worksheet should have the number 3 in all formulas, row 3 should have the number 20, row 4 should have the number 37, etc.  The next location worksheet would increase the number by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not on my work computer, so I haven't had the opportunity to test out this code, but I believe this should do what you want. If there are any issues with it, let me know, and I'll have a look at it at work tomorrow.

```
Sub replace_numbers()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim c As Range
  Dim replace_with As Long
  Dim objRegex As Object

  'Application.EnableEvents = False
  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
  'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

  With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\d+"
  End With

  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "DATA" Then
      For Each c In ws.Range("B2:M13")
        replace_with = CLng(Intersect(ws.Columns("N"), ws.Rows(c.Row)).Value)
        c.Formula = objRegex.Replace(c.Formula, replace_with)
      Next
    End If
  Next

  'Application.EnableEvents = True
  'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  'Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
  'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

If the code runs as intended, remove the apostrophes before the `Application`-calls, in order to make the code run somewhat faster.

Comment: Better now? @TedBarberJr

Comment: Thank you for your assistance eirikdaude.  This code is altering the formulas on the various location worksheets, which is ideal.  It also altered the data on the DATA worksheet but I reenter that data.  I truly appreciate your assistance with this.  Also, I'll look up some information to better understand what each line of this code does.  Thank you again!

Comment: YES!!  I really need to learn VB.  You have saved me hours of work.  Thank you again.  I truly appreciate the assistance.

Comment: If this answers your question, I would appreciate if you marked it as such. There should be a checkmark next to the top of the answer. @TedBarberJr

Answer (score 0):

You can always use something like:

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("DATA").Cells(2, 4)) And _
   IsError(Worksheets("DATA").Cells(2, 5).Value / Worksheets("DATA").Cells(2, 4).Value) Then
   ActiveCell = "NA"
Else
   ActiveCell = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(2, 5).Value / Worksheets("DATA").Cells(2, 4).Value
End If
```

Which is the formula you have translated to VBA code.

However, you must add error handlers, and other stuff according to what you have in your input data.

Comment: Again, forgive me if my original post wasn't clear.  Did I clearly describe what I'm attempting to do?